# App downgrading automatically , distributed outside of appStore for Diawi from Xcode8.2.1?

Tags: ios, distribute, diawi

I am stuck in a weird scenario , I created a build in xcode 8.2.1 by selecting distribute outside appstore then I uploaded the ipa file to diawi.com . By using the link I installed the build in my device it was running successfully but when I opened the app again its in the old version of the same app. I don't understand how it happened, I already removed the old version of the app from device before installing the new version. 
I don't think it is to do with any certificates or provisioning profile.
Please help me if someone has encountered the same issue like this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the build version while creating a build and make sure you export the ipa using correct build from archive utility.And sign out from Diawi and create a link.So none of your old builds are interfered.

Comment: Thanks a lot , it seems to work for me now. I really appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Hi Chandra , It was working fine I opened it few times but now I am facing the same problem . Yesterday I created a new build with different build number , suddenly it went back to previous version today.